# Play swf from url using Intents?

Tags: android, flash, android-intent

I am developing a simple flash arcade application but have run into a snag. I have some html come up in a webview and when you click a game I have it using an intent to open the flash file.  The problem is that is crashes! Is it possible to use intent to play a swf file?

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.bobhoil.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "flash/*");  
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can open the .swf within your webview, so you can stay inside your application

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

String url = "file:///android_asset/game.swf";

webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am playing it inside my webview but one thing is that I have an ad at the bottom of the app in a view. Is it possible to hide that when the user clicks on the swf file so that it will fill the full screen?